# How do to implement multiple select list and store on another select list in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectlist

Can anybody help me with this? I don't know what it's called so I drew a picture of it. I know you could understand how this works, just want to know what it's called and how can it be implemented in jQuery?
Thanks guys.
[image: What is this form called?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soloution is pretty simple.

Your HTML could be something like this

```
      <select name="possible" class="possible" multiple>
          <option value="one">One</option>
          <option value="two">Two</option>
      </select>

      <select name="wishlist" class="wishlist" multiple>
      </select>

      <input type="button" value="Add to wishlist" onclick="MyMoveItem();">
      <input type="button" value="Remove from wishlist" onclick="RemoveItem();">
```

And your JS

```
function MyMoveItem()
{
    var selected = $('.possible option:selected');
    selected.appendTo('.wishlist');
}


function RemoveItem()
{
    var selected = $('.wishlist option:selected');
    selected.appendTo('.possible');
}
```

Comment: Incredible.. I was thinking of a really complicated step, but this was simple and right to the point. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Think you want to remove first group and set new group onclick/event or w.e. Try to set Data-page="" attributes on each list item  and remove() / add() children via jquery. If not, please explain in more details..

Comment: He should simply use HTML list... there is no reason to use data-page, or whatever more complicated than ul and li tags and simple js function.